# Is it okay to recreate class component state behavior using useReducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

so in react hooks we may have multiple states in our component:

```
const [stateA, setStateA] = useState(0);
const [stateB, setStateB] = useState('Hello World');
const [stateC, setStateC] = useState(true);
```

but there is a case that we need to update multiple states at once. let say when clicking event:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  setStateA(prev => prev+1);
  setStateB('John Doe');
  setStateC(false);
}
```

As we can see I need to update these states 1 by 1. So to update all states at once and ensure all updates in the same batch, I tried making this reducer:

```
const stateReducer => (prev, next) {
  switch (typeof next) {
    case 'object':
      return { ...prev, ...next };
    case 'function':
      return { ...prev, ...next(prev) };
    default:
      return prev;
  }

...

const [state, setState] = useReducer(stateReducer, {
  stateA: 0,
  stateB: 'Hello World',
  stateC: true
});

...

// just set single state
setState({stateA: 0});

// set multiple state
setState({
  stateA: 5,
  stateB: 'John Doe'
});

// set multiple state with prev state
setState(prev => ({
  stateA: prev.stateA +1,
  stateB: 'John Doe',
  stateC: !prev.stateC,
}));
```

It's works! but how it gonna affect the performace? or this is okay?

Comment: *So to update all states at once and ensure all updates in the same batch* - Are you observing an actual problem with the multiple `useState` method? This sounds like a premature optimization for a problem I'm not so sure actually exists.

Answer (score 1):

Your performance will not be affected.

In the note section of the page [Functional updates in the react hooks reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) they post useReducer as an alternative for useState when we need to manage different state variables.

> Another option is useReducer, which is more suited for managing state objects that contain multiple sub-values.

The performance key does not reside in the usage of useState or useReducer itself, it's more about why do you need to use it, and as they say in the [useReducer documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) you are doing a good usage of it simplifying the way you handle this 3 state variables.

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one.

Not 100% sure about this but I think useState use useReducer internally.